PropertyControlClassFactory not available in Episerver 12?
I am migrating to Episerver CMS 12 and currently getting an error PropertyControlClassFactory does not exist in the current context.
I couln't find any dll that provides this class for CMS 12.
How can I fix this? Or any workaround?

Are you upgrading an old WebForms site? WebForms is no longer a thing since ASP.NET Core, so you'll probably want to migrate to Razor.
